# Is it possible to read x,y and z values from MAVLINK / JSON with node.js?

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm trying to list all currently saved waypoints on my UAV via node.js and MAVLINK. Therefore, I want to write the x,y and z coordinates which are contained in the MAVLINK answer into an array:

```
wparray=[];    

m.on('MISSION_ITEM', function(message, fields){
wparray.push([fields.seq,fields.x,fields.y,fields.z]);
});
```

"fields" represents all decoded MAVLINK messages:

```
{   param1: 0,
    param2: 0,
    param3: 0,
    param4: 0,
    x: 45.18074035644531,
    y: 12.4921875,
    z: 20,
    seq: 1,
    command: 16,
    target_system: 1,
    target_component: 1,
    frame: 3,
    current: 0,
    autocontinue: 1 }
```

However, I can't access the **x,y,z** values as they seem to be **reserved by node**. Any ideas how this can be solved? It doesn't throw an error - it just doesn't read the field. Thanks!

Comment: Is 'fields'  an Object or a Json string?

Comment: How did you conclude that they are reserved by Node and/or that the fields aren't being read?

Comment: "fields" is an JSON String and Atom keeps highlighting only x,y,z so I assumed that these characters are somehow reserved by Node.